# I need to have a field which value would be the id of the item, how can I achieve this?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an insert statement, the id field has auto_increment, another field must get the exact same value of the id field.

All I can think of is to create an hash, save it in the insert, then search for it with a select, retrieve the id and then insert it in the proper field.

I am also aware of the LAST_INSERT_ID() command, but I had problem in the past with it.

Are there other ways to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mysql_insert_id()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is the best way to go, unless you're manually making your own ID's.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```